# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) ОШИБКА: отношение ХХХ не существует

Tags: python, postgresql

Здравствуйте.

Решил начать использовать на девелопменте postgresql.

Всё как всегда, обычные модели, примерно такого рода:

```
class User(Base, UserMixin):
         ...
    activities = db.relationship('Activity', backref='users_activities')


class Activity(Base):

    subject = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    detail = db.Column(db.Text)

    contact_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('сontact.id'))
    org_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organisation.id'))
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'))
    created_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('profile.id'), nullable=False) 

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.id
```

но при попытке агрейдить таблицу postgres постоянно ругается на то, что отношение не существует, хотя sqlite3 с той же схемой миграции не выдаёт никаких ошибок.

Я так понимаю, что заморочка в ковычках и регистрах, но нигде не могу найти инф. как делать правильно.

**"""UPDATE"""**

Проблема так и не решилась.
В упор не вижу, что не так.

43 таблицы в БД. 
На Sqlite3 всё работает как надо, тесты проходят, создаётся и Activity и User и всё что нужно.

Ошибка :

```
[SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE activity (\n\tid SERIAL NOT NULL, \n\tcreated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, \n\tmodified_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, \n\tsubject VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, \n\tdetail TEXT, \n\torg_id INTEGER, \n\tproject_id INTEGER, \n\tcreated_by INTEGER, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(created_by) REFERENCES "user" (id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(org_id) REFERENCES organisation (id), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(project_id) REFERENCES project (id)\n)\n\n']
```

Более того. Я решил попробовать закомментить строки, отвечающие за связь этих моделей, и попробовать апгрейдить без них.

Но дошло до того, что я снёс 7 моделей :) и ошибка всё равно сыпалась и именно та же самая. То есть это системная ошибка, одна и та же, допущенная во всех моделях.

Гугление ни к чему не привело.

Может хотя бы какие-то предположения есть ?

Заранее спасибо.